# Is it possible for Pycharm to auto format my code after I finish one line and hit enter to jump to next line?

Tags: pycharm, code-formatting

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> will do the trick, but is it possible to achieve this without hitting any key?Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and **pycharm** does that. Suppose if you write a function or condition or loop if you add colon after that and hit enter **pycharm** automatically format your code.
 
Example- 
*

> def function(): in this statement if you hit enter pycharm format you
>   code and show cursor to the next line after a tab space.

*

Comment: It's a good idea,actually by doing this you add a new function in Pycharm.But in many IDE,this is processed automatically,I wonder whether Pycharm have this build-in function.